# How to build a predictive model on normalized data

Tags: predictive-modeling

I have a dataset of accounts that contain a number of users that share a subscription to a product (think Netflix family account or something like that). In order to predict whether an account will be cancelled or not I want to use the traffic patterns of each one of the users.

[image: Data shape]

Is there an algorithm out there that can take the normalised data as is to generate predictions on whether the account will be cancelled?

I'm aware of the several techniques of feature generation that could be used to denormalize the data, but it would be extremely useful if a model (or models) could be built with the data as is.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you precise what you mean by normalized data. For me normalized data is more about rescaling the data between 0 and 1 but it doesn't seems to be what you are talking about here.

Comment: By normalized I mean so in the Database sense ([wiki link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)), rather than the scale.